# using diff to compare two csv and extract value that exist one one csv but not the other

Tags: diff

i have two csv files with one column as shown in the example below. how can i use diff or any other methods to output value that exist in CSV1 and not CSV 2?

CSV1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

CSV2:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
e
e
e
```

Expected results:

```
d
c
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be very easy to answer if you had both columns of data as separate tables in a database.  In the demo below, I simply left join the first table to the second one to arrive at the answer you want:

```
SELECT t1.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.value = t2.value
WHERE t2.value IS NULL;
```

[image: screen capture of MySQL query]

### Demo

By the way, the expected output is both `c` and `d`, because these letters appear in the first csv but not the second.